# Execute two commands in single-line If -statement

Tags: if-statement, autoit

I want to execute two commands as part of a single-line `If` -statement:

Though below snippet runs without error, variable `$F_Akr_Completed` is not set to `1`, but the `MsgBox()` is displayed properly (with "F is 0").

```
$F_Akr_Completed = 0
$PID_Chi         = Run($Command)

If $F_Akr_Completed = 0 And Not ProcessExists($PID_Chi) Then $F_Akr_Completed = 1 And MsgBox(1,1,"[Info] Akron parser completed. F is " & $F_Akr_Completed)
```

Any idea why there is no syntax-error reported when it's not functional?

Answer (score 3):

There is no error, because

```
If x = x Then x And x
```

is a valid statement, and `x And x` is a logical expression. There are many ways you can do this, e.g.:

```
If Not ($F_Akr_Completed And ProcessExists($PID_Chi)) Then $F_Akr_Completed = 1 + 0 * MsgBox(1,1,"[Info]    Akron parser completed. F is " & 1)
```

But that is a bad style of coding. AutoIt is a mostly verbose language and I recommend to seperate multiple statements.

You can also assign values using the ternary operator:

```
$F_Akr_Completed = (Not ($F_Akr_Completed And ProcessExists($PID_Chi))) ? 1 : 0
```

which is the same as

```
$F_Akr_Completed = Int(Not ($F_Akr_Completed And ProcessExists($PID_Chi)))
```